# Using Comprehension and Data frames to extract data from lists of dictionary's in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I sure I should be able to find this but I have looked and I can't seem to fine how to do a few of the user cases I am looking for. I want to search a list of dictionaries and either pull back a subset or count how often a value appears.

for example from the below list I want to be able to say

return a list of all the dictionaries that contain "WAP1" in the key "AP" or return the number of lists that key "network" = "net1"

so return a new list with just the first 2 dictionary items and the number "3", based on a logical search term

I have used, wap = next((item for item in ls_dict if item['AP']=='WAP1'),'none') but this only gets the first item. I was also not sure why this does not work without using "next" and throw's this error. <generator object  at 0x7f9146cba0>

At the end of the day i want to be able to search a large list for the occurrence of a mac address and either pull out a list of all the dictionary objects that i can use for future operations, or simply count up how many times they appear.

Thank you in advance for any guidance, i know this must be simple but have been looking for a while and cant figure it out.

```
> ls_dict = [{'network': 'NET1', 'AP': 'WAP1', 'MAC': 'FF01', 'ap_mac' : 'eeeeeeeeeeee'},
           {'network': 'NET1', 'AP': 'WAP1', 'MAC': 'FF02', 'ap_mac' : 'eeeeeeeeeeee'},
           {'network': 'NET1', 'AP': 'WAP2', 'MAC': 'FF03', 'ap_mac' : 'eeeeeeeeeeee'},
           {'network': 'NET2', 'AP': 'WAP3', 'MAC': 'FF04', 'ap_mac' : 'eeeeeeeeeeee'}]
```

Comment: do you know about list comprehension, or about using the `filter` function?

Comment: I had not but since reading your comment i have started to educate my self on them and that looks what i am looking for thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pandas answer if perfectly fine but the poster and you both made comments about efficiency. If you start with a list of dictionaries, pandas is not helping from a performance perspective.

Let's create some larger data based on your example:

```py
import random

APs= [f"WAP{i}" for i in range(1, 9)]
ls_dict = [
    {'network': 'NET1', 'AP': random.choice(APs), 'MAC': 'FF01', 'ap_mac' : 'eeeeeeeeeeee'}
    for _ in range(10_000)
]
```

And now some test methods that we can verify return the same results:

```py
import pandas as pd

def t1(ls_dict):
    df = pd.DataFrame(ls_dict)
    return df[df['AP']=="WAP1"].to_dict(orient='records')

def t2(ls_dict):
    return [r for r in ls_dict if r["AP"] == "WAP1"]

print(t1(ls_dict) == t2(ls_dict))
```

That will (should) result in `True`

So memory aside, let's see how these perform using `timeit`:

```py
setup = """
import pandas as pd
import random

APs= [f"WAP{i}" for i in range(1, 9)]
ls_dict = [
    {'network': 'NET1', 'AP': random.choice(APs), 'MAC': 'FF01', 'ap_mac' : 'eeeeeeeeeeee'}
    for _ in range(10_000)
]

ls_dict = [
    {'network': 'NET1', 'AP': 'WAP1', 'MAC': 'FF01', 'ap_mac' : 'eeeeeeeeeeee'},
    {'network': 'NET1', 'AP': 'WAP1', 'MAC': 'FF02', 'ap_mac' : 'eeeeeeeeeeee'},
    {'network': 'NET1', 'AP': 'WAP2', 'MAC': 'FF03', 'ap_mac' : 'eeeeeeeeeeee'},
    {'network': 'NET2', 'AP': 'WAP3', 'MAC': 'FF04', 'ap_mac' : 'eeeeeeeeeeee'}
] * 5_000

def t1(ls_dict):
    df = pd.DataFrame(ls_dict)
    return df[df['AP']=="WAP1"].to_dict(orient='records')

def t2(ls_dict):
    return [r for r in ls_dict if r["AP"] == "WAP1"]
"""

print(f'pandas dataframe: {timeit.timeit("t1(ls_dict)", setup=setup, number=100)}')
print(f'comprehension   : {timeit.timeit("t2(ls_dict)", setup=setup, number=100)}')
```

On my system, that results in:

```
pandas dataframe: 3.5198207999928854
comprehension   : 0.08080889997654594
```

Comment: But be fair that it not a like for like comparison.  You are converting back and forth from dictionary to data frame each time.  If you move the conversion out side the timing loop it the times are more like 0.5 vs 0.3 on my Pi. And if you were to use df you would convert once to df carry out all the working which may be in my case 1000 of operations  and then convert back once at the end.

Comment: I agree that it might not be as efficient for a single operation in terms of speed for a single operation, but my comment on efficiency was more on the readability for me of the code rather than out right performance in execution. Time to develop a script is also an area of efficiency. I am sure both have a place, and based on my reading and some of the operation I am looking for, data frames do look like they will make manipulating the data easier, such as extracting and sorting and comparing multiply sets of data.

Comment: Absolutely, if your task was to do a bunch of stuff on a data frame then clearly that could be a factor. You did not mention the possibility of 1000s of operation. Note though that the comprehension is 30x more performant so it still might come out a head 

Comment: By the way cheers for drawing my attention to "timeit" function. I only started playing with python lately and good to pick up new tips.

Comment: It actually interesting playing around with this seeing when one is faster than the other. You right my question was based on a simplified user case, where comprehension would be the right method. I am sure I will be using both in the final script ;)

Comment: I find `timeit` to be kind of addictive myself :-)

Comment: Another reason to use Data frames would be if you want to integrate with Power BI, which i did not know i wanted to do but have now found out i need to :)

Answer (score 1):

If the list is large you might want to use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) in order to work on dataframes. You can always export (list of) dictionaries with `to_dict`:

```
import pandas as pd

ls_dict = [{'network': 'NET1', 'AP': 'WAP1', 'MAC': 'FF01', 'ap_mac' : 'eeeeeeeeeeee'},
           {'network': 'NET1', 'AP': 'WAP1', 'MAC': 'FF02', 'ap_mac' : 'eeeeeeeeeeee'},
           {'network': 'NET1', 'AP': 'WAP2', 'MAC': 'FF03', 'ap_mac' : 'eeeeeeeeeeee'},
           {'network': 'NET2', 'AP': 'WAP3', 'MAC': 'FF04', 'ap_mac' : 'eeeeeeeeeeee'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(ls_dict)
df[df['AP']=="WAP1"].to_dict(orient='record'))
```

Output:

```
[{'network': 'NET1', 'AP': 'WAP1', 'MAC': 'FF01', 'ap_mac': 'eeeeeeeeeeee'},
{'network': 'NET1', 'AP': 'WAP1', 'MAC': 'FF02', 'ap_mac': 'eeeeeeeeeeee'}]
```

Or:

```
len(df[df['network']=="NET1"]) # returns 3
```

Comment: Thank you I will look this up, some lists might be >10,000  and this looked to be a neat and efficient solution thank you for your input. apricate you taking the time to educate.